# Nesting fields in serialization use custom fields with Django REST framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to serialize foreikey to another name.
For example:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(..)

class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, ...)
    title = models.CharField(...)


class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = '__all__'
```

when use `BlogSerializer(blog_instance).data` can get the data:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "user": 1,
  "user_info": {"id": 1, "user_name": "admin"},
  "title": "hello world"
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Do you want to add the `user_info` field with the data you specified in the example?

Comment: @Bary12 Yes, I want to use two fields to represent user information, `user`  for ensure that create and retrieve data are same and `user_info`  is read_only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want a different representation for the user, you can make this trick to change that:

```
class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        # here you override the 'user' field, you can either use a dictionary
        ret['user'] = {"id": instance.user.id, "user_name": instance.user.user_name}

        # or better yet create an actual UserSerializer and get that representation, eg.
        # ret['user'] = UserSerializer(context=self.context).to_representation(instance.user)

        return ret
```

Answer (score 1):

Just create another serializer for User and add it as any field you want in the BlogSerializer. For example:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username')

class BlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_info = UserSerializer(source='user')
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'user_info', 'title')
```

Though I don't see much need of `user` with just the id since `user_info` already includes the id and other info. But if that is what you want then this is how to implement it